# Automatic Slide show?

Tags: android

HI,

Want to implement automatic slideshow in my application, the images should change automatically with some time. Should look like a flash type changing screens,
Please help?

Answer (score 0):

> Want to implement automatic slideshow in my application, the images should change automatically with some time.

Use `ImageView` and `postDelayed()`.

> Should look like a flash type changing screens

I have no idea what this means.

Comment: Hi I have implemented postDelayed and here is my code,but failed to get the output, images not sliding.private ImageView imgView;
    @Overridepublic void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);setContentView(R.layout.main);imgView = (ImageView )findViewById(R.id.image1);        
        final Runnable r = new Runnable(){ public void run() 
            {
             imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);
                imgView.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };

        imgView.postDelayed(r, 1000);

    }